# Is there a way to make functions remember previous results?

Tags: javascript

I don't really know how to explain this problem.

```
console.log(fib_next(),fib_next(), fib_next())
```

needs to print out

```
1 2 3
```

basically everytime fib_next() is called, it sums up the previous 2 calls of the function.

Comment: Might want to look into [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)

Answer (score 2):

Define a variable outside the definition of `fib_next` so `fib_next` can see it and increment it:

```js
let counter = 1;
const fib_next = () => counter++;

console.log(fib_next(),fib_next(), fib_next())
```

Or, to fully encapsulate the scope, use an IIFE:

```js
const fib_next = (() => {
  let counter = 1;
  return () => counter++;
})();

console.log(fib_next(),fib_next(), fib_next())
```

Comment: Sorry, but I forgot to mention but fib_next is a fibonacci  sequence and everytime it's called it sums the previous two fib_next's.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want a function that, when called, returns the next [`Fibonacci number`](https://www.livescience.com/37470-fibonacci-sequence.html).

There are more than one ways to achieve the desired result. One way would be to use a [`generator function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).

Following code snippet shows an example that prints first 5 Fibonacci numbers.

```js
function* fib_next() {
  yield 0;
  yield 1;
  let temp, prev = 0, curr = 1;

  while (true) {
    temp = curr + prev;
    yield temp;
    prev = curr;
    curr = temp;
  }
}

const nextFibNum = fib_next();
// print first 5 fibonacci numbers
let i = 1;
while (i <= 5) {
  console.log(nextFibNum.next().value);
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not realy understand your issue but... I guess if you save the return the result of each Function in a Global Var this can work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the generator function that [Yousaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6094348/yousaf) said, I modified it a bit

```
let fib_next = (() => {
  let curr = 1;
  let prev = 0;

    return () => {
      let tmp = curr + prev;
      let retval = tmp;
      prev = curr;
      curr = tmp;

      return retval;
    };
})();

console.log(fib_next(), fib_next(), fib_next(), fib_next(), fib_next(), fib_next());
// prints 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13
```